# ModelState validation fails for dictionary where keys are enums

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, enums, json.net

I have a model that has the following property:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MapConvertor))]
[IsValidSomeObject]
public Dictionary<SomeEnum, decimal> SomeMap { get; set; }
```

And I created the following custom `ValidationAttribute` class to validate it:

```
public class IsValidSomeObjectAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

But when I used `modelState.IsValid`, it says my object is not valid because in dictionary all possible `SomeEnum` key values do not exist and interestingly that custom validation class does not even run when I use the debugger. I am wondering is there a way to imply that all possible key values do not necessary needs to be present in dictionary. Thank you.

Update 1: My custom validation runs only when I supply all possible enum values for the dictionary and then it tries to validate. **I think what is happening is .NET's default validation runs first and then it runs my custom validation.**

Update 2: I added custom JSON converter, this converter runs but still I get ModelState not valid. I don't think model state validation is even using my custom `ValidationAttribute`.

```
public class MapConvertor : JsonConverter
{
    // serializing
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // write retVal to stream
        writer.WriteValue(value);
    }

    // de-serializing
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dictionary = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<SomeEnum, decimal>>(reader);

        // if key is not in enum, then add it
        foreach (SomeEnum @enum in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum)))
        {
            if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(@enum)) dictionary.Add(@enum, 1);
        }

        return dictionary;
    }

    // always true to indicate object can be serialized/de-serialized
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the exact error message. it will help me to identify which Validator is failing the model state

Comment: What is happening is that custom JSON converter runs and fills dictionary with all possible key values but my custom ValidationAttribute does not run because model state is invalid (I have not provided key value pair in my JSON for one of enum of SomeEnum). Exception message: `Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Decimal'.` I believe the model state validator has it's own converter that does not even uses my custom JSON converter.

Comment: Is this also happening if you use `Dictionary<SomeEnum?, decimal>` ?